# What resource is the id parameter in ArrayAdapter constructor?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out what the resource id is in the ArrayAdapter constructor.  I have some other questions, too:

- What is it used for?
- Why should it point to some text?
- Isn't the purpose of `ArrayAdapter` to push any kind of items to it?
- Why does it say only `TextView`?
- Can't I use `ArrayAdapter<View>` where `View` can be any `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is it used for

If supplied, it points to the ID of a `TextView` inside of the row layout. If it is not supplied, and you are using the default `getView()` implementation of `ArrayAdapter`, then the row layout must *be* a `TextView`.

> and why it should point to some text

Because the built-in implementation of `getView()` on `ArrayAdapter` wants to take `toString()` of the model object and put that text into a `TextView`.

> why does it say only TextView?

Because that is what the built-in implementation of `getView()` on `ArrayAdapter` expects.

> can't i used arrayadapter where view can be any view ?

Yes, you can. However, if you do not have a `TextView` in your row, you cannot use the built-in implementation of `getView()` and must comoletely override it.

Answer (score 1):

The layout you want to use for that ArrayAdapter instance.

Usually you can use a default one from android: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Why it is only a TextView: because that's how the ArrayAdapter is implemented. It has to contain a TextView for sorting/filtering etc

If you want a custom view you can create a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter and you override getView(...)

Comment: Indeed, if you make custom list items and override getView() you can just set it to a default one from Android.